# Using pandas to check stability in data

Tags: data-visualization, pandas

I have a `conversions` table & I am trying to identify **Are the conversions in the 'conversions' table stable over time? to identify Any pattern?**

```
df = df1.sort_values('conv_date', ascending=True)
plt.plot(df['conv_date'], df['revenue'] ,'*')
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Revenue')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I have a plot that looks like this considering the time on the x-axis and revenue on the y-axis. Is there a way to determine stability from such a graph or are there any alternatives to do this?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you mean by "stable"? Is the time series stationary? Is there a trend? A structural break? Constant variance?

Comment: Yes, from my plot I see there is no trend (increasing or decreasing) as such so can I conclude that there is no definitive pattern?

Comment: Because so many points are overplotted, I cannot see how anyone could discern a trend.  There could be *enormous* changes in mean revenue lurking here.  Consider using a more perspicuous plot.  Some combination of visualization technique (boxplots, violin plots, etc) and a suitable transformation (e.g., log revenue) will help.